# hook_user_insert() doesn't fire a custom rule

Tags: 7, rules

The operation should be as follows: Trigger an event after registering a new user.

- test_rules_rules_event_info (example_rule_event) **it's my event**
- test_rules_user_insert **when a user is registered**
- test_rules_customFunction **the function that is called by the rule**

Therefore, when a user is registered, my event is triggered, and `test_rules_customFunction() is called by running the PHP code set by the Rules interface.
When the user is created from the UI, this is done. When the user is programmatically created, this doesn't happen.

The code I am using is the following.

```php
function test_rules_rules_event_info() {
  return array(
    'example_rule_event' => array(
      'label' => t('Regola test, quando un utente è registrato'),
      'module' => 'test_rules',
      'group' => 'test' ,
      'variables' => array(
        'current_user' => array('type' => 'user', 'label' => t('The current user.')),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
    
function test_rules_user_insert(&$edit, $account, $category) {
  watchdog("test_rules_user_insert", '<pre>' . print_r( $account, true) . '</pre>');
  rules_invoke_event('example_rule_event', $account);
}
    
function test_rules_customFunction($current_user){
  watchdog("test_rules_customFunction", '<pre>' . print_r( $current_user, true) . '</pre>');
  var_dump($current_user);
  exit;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Are you sure `test_rules_customFunction()` has been associated to the right event? From what I can find googling, there isn't anything in the code that is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for editing the question.

Comment: I have read that it could be an execution order problem, and that it would be solvable by the hook `hook_module_implements_alter`
@kiamlaluno

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with Rules - if your hook isn't being run, then it has nothing to do with the code in your hook ... If hook_user_insert() isn't being called when you create a user programmatically, then that may be because you're not creating the user using the Drupal API?